# Use qualified hostname to access minikube service instead of localhost/127.0.0.1?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, localhost, ip, minikube

I am running minikube on Windows. I am starting a pod and NodePort like this:

```
minikube start
kubectl apply -f pod.yml
kubectl apply -f service.yml
kubectl port-forward service/sample-web-service 31111:80
```

At this point, I can access my sample web service in a browser using:

```
localhost:31111
```

and

```
127.0.0.1:31111
```

Note, I get no response trying to access the service using the ip returned by `minikube ip` described here:

https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#getting-the-nodeport-using-kubectl

Is it possible to also access my sample web service using a qualified hostname (i.e. the `Full Computer Name` found in `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System`)? I tried the following in a browser but didn't get a response:

```
my-windows-pc-name.mydomain.com:31111
```

I am on a VPN and tried turning it off but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
kubectl port-forward service/sample-web-service --address 0.0.0.0 31111:80
```